# How to use numbers split with comma in case when clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to use code like this

```
declare @Class varchar(20) 
set @Class = '4,6,8'

select 
    case when @Class in (1, 2) 
            then 1 
            else 0 
    end
```

or

```
Select 
    case when '4,6,8' in (1,2) 
       then 1 
       else 0 
    end
```

This returns an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '4,6,8' to data type int.

Is there a way to use this split numbers in case when clause?

Update: Actually I use this code within C# code

```
private string Class()
    {
        if (this.RdFac.Checked)
        {
            return "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18";
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.CmbBrClass.SelectedValue.ToString() == "12")
            {
                return "12,16,18";
            }
        }
  }

private void ShwoResults_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       dataTable = @"select 
        case when "+Class()+" in (1, 2) 
                then 1 
                else 0 
            end"
    }
```

Comment: Your data model has a problem, and you should not be using CSV data this way in SQL Server.  If you can post the table(s) you are using, perhaps some suggestions could be made.

Comment: What matching you are looking for between list '4,6,8' AND '1,2'?

Comment: i'm trying to avoid '4,6,8' from the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this...

In SQL Server below 2012:-

```
    DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(100) = '12,14,15,1,2'
    ;WITH cte AS
    (
       SELECT 
          CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(t.val,',','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
          FROM (SELECT @string) AS t(val)
    ),
    ct as (
    SELECT 
        m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)') as col
    FROM cte
    CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)
    ),
    ctfinal as (
          SELECT CASE WHEN CAST(col AS int) IN ( 1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS RES FROM ct 
    )
    SELECT TOP 1 FROM ctfinal ORDER BY RES DESC
```

or

```
    declare @Class varchar(20) 
    set @Class = '4,6,8,1'

    select 
        case when (@Class like '%1%' or @Class like '%2%')
                then 1 
                else 0 
        end
```

For SQL Server 2012 and above:-

```
    declare @Class varchar(20) 
    set @Class = '4,6,8,1'

    ; with cte as (
    select case when value in (1, 2) 
    then 1 else 0 end as res 
    from STRING_SPLIT ( @Class , ',' )
    ) 
    select top 1 res from cte order by res desc
```

For comparing your `int` value, first you need to bifurcate your string into individual `int` values in `rows`. Then only you may check them in given condition.

Although this `in (1,2)` is still static in this query.

Comment: The second statment helped .. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> Error You are try to compare int with varchar

This should work for you

```
declare @Class varchar(20) 
set @Class = '4,6,8,1'

select 
case
when value in (1, 2) 
then 1 
else 0 end as result 
from STRING_SPLIT ( @Class , ',' )
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY**: Below is the immediate solution if you don't have more values to compare

**--In case of value**

```
CASE WHEN ('1' IN (4,6,8) OR '2' IN (4,6,8)) 
THEN 1 
ELSE 0 END
```

**--In case of variable**

```
CASE WHEN ('1' IN (@Class) OR '2' IN (@Class)) 
THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Class varchar(20)   
set @Class='4,6,8'  
DECLARE @intFlag INT  
DECLARE @temp INT  
SET @intFlag = 0  
WHILE (LEN(@Class)>0)  
BEGIN  
 if (CHARINDEX(',',@Class)=0)  
 begin  
 set @temp=@Class  
 set @Class=''  
 end  
 else 
 begin  
set @temp= SUBSTRING(@Class,1,CHARINDEX(',',@Class)-1)   
set @Class= SUBSTRING(@Class,CHARINDEX(',',@Class)+1,len(@Class)-CHARINDEX(',',@Class))
end   
set @intFlag= case when @temp in (1,2) then 1  else 0 end  
END  
select @intFlag
```

Comment: Please provide context for your code. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) link for more details on how to write a good answer.